# typescript - object literal with array syntax

Tags: typescript

I had not come across such a notation:

```
function(a: number,
sort?: { order: -1 | 1; sortBy: string }[] ){
//function body here
}
```

Specifially I'm interested in the sort parameter.

I can only understand that `sort` is an optional argument (I can't even say for sure if it's an object literal since there's no `,`).
What does this syntax read? What type of variable is it? Why is there a `;` instead of a `,`(BTW that is not a typo). What does `{...}[]` indicate?

Comment: Please consider modifying the code in this question so as to constitute a [mcve] which, when dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WKkK8W), clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Such code should not have unrelated errors (e.g., `public station function` is not valid). This will allow those who want to help you to immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  And it will make it so that any answer you get is testable against a well-defined use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break it down

```
{ order: -1 | 1; sortBy: string }[]
```

The brackets at the end indicate an array. So it's an array of something, where that something is

```
{ order: -1 | 1; sortBy: string }
```

The objects in the array must have an `order` field which is either `1` or `-1` and a `sortBy` field which must be a `string`.

Finally, as you've pointed out, the `?` after the argument name makes it optional. So `sort` is an optional array of objects which have two fields: `order` and `sortBy`.

I certainly understand your confusion, as this is a complicated type signature. If I was writing this, it'd probably make more sense to extract it into an interface or an object type.

```
type SortParam = { order: -1 | 1, sortBy: string }

SortParam[]
```

As for the comma versus the semicolon, don't sweat it. Typescript lets you interchange the two in several situations. Use the one you prefer and don't worry about it.

Comment: is `;` interchangable in object definitions as well or type specifications?

Comment: how would I specify that the `order` field should be a `number` or an array of object literals(without specifying any fields) would order: number | {}[] do the trick?

Comment: The semicolon thing is just in types; TS tries to maintain compatibility with JS in a lot of situations, including object literals. As for your second question, the answer is [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types). If you want that written out in more detail, it's probably worth asking a new question on here, for the sake of organization.

Comment: okay. Just one more clarification, is `order: -1|1` also providing a default value? e.g. nothing was passed in the order field, then -1 would be the default value?

Comment: No, `-1|1` means the value must be a number which is either `-1` or `1`. The `order` field, as written, is required.

Answer (score 2):

The `sort` parameter is optional as indicated by the `?` but if you do supply one it must conform to the type specified to the right of the `:` which is of type `{ order: -1 | 1; sortBy: string }[]`. That type means it is an array of objects whose shape is `{ order: -1 | 1; sortBy: string }`.

The presence of `;` is because in Typescript you can delimit fields of an object type by either `;` or `,` interchangeably.

This is identical but may read clearer to you:

```
type SortSpecification = {
  order: -1 | 1;
  sortBy: string;
};

const func = (a: number, sort?: SortSpecification[]) => {
  /* ... */
}
```

And these would all be valid calls to it:

```
func(42);
func(42, [{ order: 1, sortBy: 'foo' }]);
func(42, [{ order: 1, sortBy: 'foo' }, { order: -1, sortBy: 'bar' }]);
```

Comment: how would I specify that the order field should be a number or an array of object literals(without specifying any fields) would order: number | {}[] do the trick?